# Resources for fast fixed point algorithms

Tags: algorithm, numerical-methods, fixed-point

Looking for essentially what is posted in this much older thread

https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/20444/books-resources-for-implementing-various-mathematical-functions-in-fixed-point-a

It would seem that there are many well known "tricks" for efficient algorithm performance using fixed point (on basically any hardware that lacks floating point support) but I've been struggling to find good resources on this stuff as a beginner. Most pages just seem to cover little bits and pieces, or one particular algorithm. What I'm looking for is webpages/books etc that give a more comprehensive overview of the topic.

Comment: Please note that questions asking for recommendations of off-site resources such as books or tutorials are considered off-topic at SO.